# IllegalStateException in ListAdapter's onChildClick

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I have a listAdapter, and when I click on one of its child views ,then sometimes( RARELY though ), I get the following exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState.
```

Code:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onChildClick( ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id ) 
 {
     OBJ obj = objListAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
     mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().
     addToBackStack(null).
     setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_fade_in, R.animator.fragment_fade_out, R.animator.fragment_fade_in, R.animator.fragment_fade_out).
     add(R.id.mainActFrmFragmentContainerBack,
                    ObjDisplayfragment.getFragment(......),ObjDisplayfragment.TAG).commit();
     return false;
 }
```

Now, I've read about the state loss (http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) , and I know I should avoid performing transactions inside asynchronous callback methods.
However, in this case , I have no other choice.

Comment: Have you tried with *commitAllowingStateLoss()* instead of *commit()*?

Comment: Well , I can. But as it's highly recommended avoiding that, I was looking for a more "better practice" solution. If there is one , that is. 
Thanks